# Excel - VBA - Range Selection Slows Down PC

Tags: excel, range, vba

Is there a way to turn these commands into one?

```
Worksheets("Agent html").Select
Range(Cells(7, TotalCallsRow), Cells(lastrow, TotalCallsRow)).Copy
```

When i give:

```
Worksheets("Agent html").Range(Cells(7, TotalCallsRow), Cells(lastrow, TotalCallsRow)).Copy
```

It returns me error

Application Defined or object-defined error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
Worksheets("Agent html").Range(Worksheets("Agent html").Cells(7, TotalCallsRow), Worksheets("Agent html").Cells(lastrow, TotalCallsRow)).Copy
```

It may be cleaner to define the worksheet as an object variable like:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Agent html")

ws.Range(ws.Cells(7, TotalCallsRow), ws.Cells(lastrow, TotalCallsRow)).Copy
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Cells` within `Range`, I'm not sure that's allowed. Either way, try to not use `.Select`

```
Dim wksht As Worksheet
Set wksht = Worksheets("Agent html")
Dim rng As Range
rng = wksht.Range(Cells(7, TotalCallsRow), Cells(lastrow, TotalCallsRow))
rng.Copy
```

Will do what you are asking above without selecting anything. I've not tested the `Range(Cells` but I can't help with that as I don't know what `TotalCallsRow` is?

Comment: TotalCallsRow is just the number of a column. Thanks man, it works!